# Вынос значения за предел функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def podbor(string, length, lib):
    if len(string) == length:
        return
    for char in lib:
        temp = string + char
        print(temp)
        podbor(temp, length, lib)

podbor("", 3, "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Есть такая функция. В данном случае выводит возможные трехзначные комбинации используя словарь символов. 
Вопрос, а как вывести temp за пределы функции?
Допустим, после функции написать "х = комбинации из функции".

Comment: Попробуйте возврат значения return temp?

Comment: Примите ответ если он вам помог(галочка около ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не верно идет вывод, так как выводятся не только последовательности длины 3, но и меньшей. Вот пример в котором генерируется список всех последовательностей заданной длины.

```
def podbor(string, length, lib, result):
    if len(string) == length:
        result.append(string)
        return
    for char in lib:
        temp = string + char
        podbor(temp, length, lib, result)

result=[]
podbor("", 3, "01234",result)
print(result)
```

Comment: Ну а где ответ на вопрос? :"Вынос значения за предел функции?"

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica это переменная result

Comment: Но с return лучше.